# Error when making a spotify voice assistant

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi there so I wanted to make a spotify voice assistant and found a tutorial of a person who just went through his code and explained it and left a github link down below and I used that and changed the setting to work for me but i'm getting an annoying error I'll put the code for the 3 files I have main.py, pepper.py and setup.txt

main.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from speech_recognition import Microphone, Recognizer, UnknownValueError
import spotipy as sp
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

from pepper import *

# Set variables from setup.txt
setup = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Yousif\Documents\Python spotify\setup.txt', sep='=', index_col=0, squeeze=True, header=None)
client_id = setup['client_id']
client_secret = setup['client_secret']
device_name = setup['device_name']
redirect_uri = setup['redirect_uri']
scope = setup['scope']
username = setup['username']

# Connecting to the Spotify account
auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    scope=scope,
    username=username)
spotify = sp.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

# Selecting device to play from
devices = spotify.devices()
deviceID = None
for d in devices['devices']:
    d['name'] = d['name'].replace('’', '\'')
    if d['name'] == device_name:
        deviceID = d['id']
        break

# Setup microphone and speech recognizer
r = Recognizer()
m = None
input_mic = 'High Definition Audio Device'  # Use whatever is your desired input
for i, microphone_name in enumerate(Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    if microphone_name == "High Definition Audio Device":
        m = Microphone(device_index=i)

while True:
    with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source=source)
        audio = r.listen(source=source)

    command = None
    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio).lower()
    except UnknownValueError:
        continue

    print(command)
    words = command.split()
    if len(words) <= 1:
        print('Could not understand. Try again')
        continue

    name = ' '.join(words[1:])
    try:
        if words[0] == 'album':
            uri = get_album_uri(spotify=spotify, name=name)
            play_album(spotify=spotify, device_id=deviceID, uri=uri)
        elif words[0] == 'artist':
            uri = get_artist_uri(spotify=spotify, name=name)
            play_artist(spotify=spotify, device_id=deviceID, uri=uri)
        elif words[0] == 'play':
            uri = get_track_uri(spotify=spotify, name=name)
            play_track(spotify=spotify, device_id=deviceID, uri=uri)
        else:
            print('Specify either "album", "artist" or "play". Try Again')
    except InvalidSearchError:
        print('InvalidSearchError. Try Again')
```

pepper.py:

```
from spotipy import Spotify


class InvalidSearchError(Exception):
    pass


def get_album_uri(spotify: Spotify, name: str) -> str:
    """
    :param spotify: Spotify object to make the search from
    :param name: album name
    :return: Spotify uri of the desired album
    """

    # Replace all spaces in name with '+'
    original = name
    name = name.replace(' ', '+')

    results = spotify.search(q=name, limit=1, type='album')
    if not results['albums']['items']:
        raise InvalidSearchError(f'No album named "{original}"')
    album_uri = results['albums']['items'][0]['uri']
    return album_uri


def get_artist_uri(spotify: Spotify, name: str) -> str:
    """
    :param spotify: Spotify object to make the search from
    :param name: album name
    :return: Spotify uri of the desired artist
    """

    # Replace all spaces in name with '+'
    original = name
    name = name.replace(' ', '+')

    results = spotify.search(q=name, limit=1, type='artist')
    if not results['artists']['items']:
        raise InvalidSearchError(f'No artist named "{original}"')
    artist_uri = results['artists']['items'][0]['uri']
    print(results['artists']['items'][0]['name'])
    return artist_uri


def get_track_uri(spotify: Spotify, name: str) -> str:
    """
    :param spotify: Spotify object to make the search from
    :param name: track name
    :return: Spotify uri of the desired track
    """

    # Replace all spaces in name with '+'
    original = name
    name = name.replace(' ', '+')

    results = spotify.search(q=name, limit=1, type='track')
    if not results['tracks']['items']:
        raise InvalidSearchError(f'No track named "{original}"')
    track_uri = results['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
    return track_uri


def play_album(spotify=None, device_id=None, uri=None):
    spotify.start_playback(device_id=device_id, context_uri=uri)


def play_artist(spotify=None, device_id=None, uri=None):
    spotify.start_playback(device_id=device_id, context_uri=uri)


def play_track(spotify=None, device_id=None, uri=None):
    spotify.start_playback(device_id=device_id, uris=[uri])
```

and setup.txt:

```
client_id=...
client_secret=...
device_name=Yousif
redirect_uri=https://yousifisdaddy.com/
username=wsk5vzl3hw3i611coxgxog2il
scope=user-read-private user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state
```

and I did put my redirect uri thats found in my spotify app and i put my client id and secret id and my setup.txt location but obviously had to blur out the client id and secret id

And the error I got is:

```
  File "c:/Users/Yousif/Documents/Python spotify/main.py", line 9
    setup = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Yousif\Documents\Python spotify\setup.txt', sep='=', index_col=0, squeeze=True, header=None)
                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```py
setup = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Yousif\Documents\Python spotify\setup.txt', sep='=', index_col=0, squeeze=True, header=None)
```

to

```py
setup = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Yousif\Documents\Python spotify\setup.txt', sep='=', index_col=0, squeeze=True, header=None)
```

Marking the path as a raw string will prevent backslash escapes from kicking in.

Reason for this:

Python uses [string escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-18) to allow for unicode support:

From the docs:

```py
\N{name}: Character named name in the Unicode database
\uxxxx: Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx
\Uxxxxxxxx: Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: I did and I got this error ``` File "c:/Users/Yousif/Documents/Python spotify/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    setup = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Yousif\Documents\Python spotify\setup.txt', sep='=', index_col=0, squeeze=True, header=None)
  File "C:\Users\Yousif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds

Comment: File "C:\Users\Yousif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Yousif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Yousif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Yousif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 540, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: "No columns to parse from file" is a different error. The error that this question is regarding looks to be solved. :)

Comment: but the text turned red does that mean anything?

Comment: If you hover over the red text does it say any warnings? What IDE are you using?

Comment: No it doesnt and i havent gotten any problems so I think it's solved and im using visual studio

Comment: The fact that you are getting a `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file` means that it doesn't like the format of the file. For figuring that part out, I'd recommend making a new python script with just the file opening/reading part for debugging purposes. Also, if my answer helped you solve your problem, please consider leaving an upvote and "accepting" my answer by using the green checkmark.

Comment: Alright thank you and i have to accept it in 2 minutes